# Manual transporting of class through the SAP CTS, which objects to include?

Tags: abap, release-management

Faced with a dependency issue, I need to manually transport a single class in a transport request to go live before a list of other transports.

I've written a `R3TR CLAS` entry to the Object List but now I'm worried that this would only include the class header and not the full implementation. In that case I believe I'd have to also transport all individual methods as `LIMU METH` entries in the Object List. In theory the header would be sufficient as the code won't actually run in production, I just need the method definition to exist as there's a source code reference to it in the transports that actually have to go live. But I assume that if this does only transport the header, the activation will fail because it would be lacking the implementation.

**When transporting a class, is a single `R3TR CLAS` object list entry sufficient or should I include all methods as `LIMU METH` entries in the object list as well?**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

R3TR CLAS ... is enough. It will include the class as a whole (header, methods, implementations, etc.)

On the other hand, if there is any Z... object (table, structures, data elements, etc) used in the class and they are not in the target system yet, than these also have to be included, otherwise the import will fail.

Comment: Would be nice to have a source to back up this claim but after a successful go-live I can confirm that this is correct. :)